# Itertools Groupby returns None when appending list to dict

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following code on which I'm grouping by a value in a particular dictionary:

```
from itertools import groupby
def group_owners(files):
    # sort data before using groupby
    files = dict(sorted(files.items()))

    # create the groupby which will return an iterator containing a key (string) and a group which itself is a iterator
    # in order to store this group iterator is necessary to initialize an empty data strcturure first
    iterator = groupby(files,lambda x: files[x])
    
    groups = []

    return {k:groups.append(list(g)) for k,g in iterator}

        

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    files = {
        'Input.txt': 'Randy',
        'Code.py': 'Stan',
        'Input2.txt': 'James',
        'Output.txt': 'Randy'
    }   
    print(group_owners(files))
```

This code returns me that:

```
{'Stan': None, 'Randy': None, 'James': None}
```

I was expecting a list in place of `None` with the groups for each key, in fact when I debug I can see that a list of lists is being created but at the end of program `None` is returned. I also would like to have only a flat list and not a list of lists.

My expected output is:

```
{'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Input.txt','Output.txt'], 'James': 'Input2.txt'}
```

If I use instead:

`{k:list(g) for k,g in iterator}` what I get is:

```
{'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Output.txt'], 'James': ['Input2.txt']}
```

I believe because of this fact, quoting form Python docs:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
> iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
> groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
> So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: groups.append appends to the list, but returns None

Comment: just do: `{k:list(g) for k,g in iterator}`? Other than that what is the expected output?

Comment: your solution returns me that `{'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Output.txt'], 'James': ['Input2.txt']}` but `Randy` should be `{'Randy':['Input.txt','Output.txt']}`

Comment: Basically you want a reverse dictionary?

Comment: hum no, I just want the collections of groups returned from the key I'm grouping by. Since Randy is one of the keys the itertools groupby method should return a list with 2 elements from Randy

Comment: Again please add the expected output to the question and also a clear explanation

Comment: just added the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def group_owners_v2(files):
    mp = defaultdict(list) 
    for key, value in files.items(): 
        mp[value].append(key)
    return dict(mp)
```

The output will be :

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'James': ['Input2.txt']}
```

Comment: don’t forget to sort

Comment: thanks but I'm not interested into a non itertools solution, I know how to do it without using itertools. I'm essentially trying to learn the `groupby` method

Comment: @adirabargil you're right !

Comment: @moth stack-overflow isn’t for homework solving issues. when you represent a problem, any solution is valid as long as it give the expected output in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I was not sorting correctly by the `value` instead of the `key` in `files`:

Here is a solution that keeps files as `dict` and does not convert into a list of tuples, it is crucial to sort the data first when using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def group_owners(files):
    # sort dict
    files = dict(sorted(files.items(),key = lambda x: x[1]))
    
    # create groupby iterator 
    iterator = groupby(files, key=lambda x: files[x])
    
    # return keys with their respective groups
    return {k:list(g) for k,g in iterator}


if __name__=='__main__':
    files = {
        'Input.txt': 'Randy',
        'Code.py': 'Stan',
        'Input2.txt': 'James',
        'Output.txt': 'Randy'
    }

    print(group_owners(files))
```

**Output**

```
{'James': ['Input2.txt'], 'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

Comment: This is the solution to fix the problem of the question, it was missing to sort by names and not by files. Notice the `sort` is _n*log(n)_ so quite expensive... I would recommend to use another way